# Asp.net webmethod as webservice?

Tags: asp.net, asmx, webmethod

i have a asp.net webapplication (VS2010, C#) and it aspx page has webmethod that are used for AJAX call (all is fine here).

But i need to use this webmethod (GetEmployeeDetails) outside the asp.net application - say, i need to use this as webservice from another client application - is this possible??

My current webmethod code in .aspx.cs page is :-

```
:
using System.Web.Services;
:
public partial class EmployeeManagement_ViewLeaveList : System.Web.UI.Page
{

[WebMethod]
    public static Object GetEmployeeDetails(int iEmpID)
    {
        :
        :
        return obj;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

the service will be be exposed as

\EmployeeManagement_ViewLeaveList.aspx\GetEmployeeDetails

You can use this to be called by other pages. However it is recommended to use separate service instead of this.